# Allure integration with NUnit 3 in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, allure, nunit-3.0

I am using **NUnit 3** in **.Net Core** to run unit tests. For reporting I wish to use Allure. The issue am experiencing is that I can only add the **NUnit.Allure** nuget package to the (.net core) project, but the namespace cannot be resolved. Are there any plans to perhaps add Allure support for .Net Core in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Allure with .Net Core 3.1.
These are the steps I followed:

1. Add Allure.Commons and NUnit.Allure to your test project.
2. Add allureConfig.json file to your test project and ensure to set it to be copied to the output directory
3. Add the [AllureNUnit] to your test classes

That is all!. You will get the output file generated by allure in the location you specified in the allureConfig.json. With those files you will be able to generate the report.